# Set all calculation to be performed to a given precision in python / numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, precision

Is there a way to set precision for all calculations to be performed within a Python program? Or at least to define a thresholds within which a value will be set to 0 in all calculations?  Maybe at least in the calculation performed by a particular package, say, `numpy`?  Some kind of global parameter, maybe?

Comment: we use `np.isclose` and `np.allclose` to test numpy float arraya. `mpmath` is used for multiprecision, but does not work in numpy.

Comment: @hpaulj  Thank you for taking time to read and comment on my post. I am familiar with these two `numpy` functions, but I was looking for some kind of global parameter that tells `numpy` to set all numbers close to `0` to `0` during all calculations performed by all `numpy` functions/methods, rather than having to catch this myself afterwards.

Comment: `numpy` gets most of its speed by doing all calculations in C code.  I'm not an expert in that, but my sense is that the emphasis is on fast efficient calls, without a whole lot of checks and bells and whistles.  Other (recent) SO have shown that it doesn't even pay attention to most overflow flags.

Comment: What is your goal? When performing calculations, it is best practice to round only the final value. If you round in intermediate steps, you will lose accuracy. For example, say I want to do `100.0*(0.5*0.01)` and get my final result to 1 decimal of precision. We know the final answer is actually `0.5`, but if we round in the middle we'll first compute what's in the parenthesis and get `0.5*0.01 = 0.005`, which we'd round down to `0.0`, which will give a final answer of `0.0`. Clearly, rounding in the middle produces very inaccurate results.